# Does relative positive definiteness have a good name?

Tags: matrices, soft-question

Often, when there are two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A-B$ is positive definite, this relationship is written $A \gt B$, $A \succ B$ or similar. It has the advantage of being consistent with the usual $\gt$ relation when $A$ and $B$ are scalars.

The use of this notation is not completely transparent, so one ends up writing something like:

> ... where $A \gt B$ denotes the positive-definiteness of the matrix $A-B$.

thereby defeating the point of writing it in this concise way. One might as well just write "$A-B$ *is positive definite*" from the start. So, **I was wondering if there was a more succinct way of describing the $\gt$ relationship** in this case? I like the notation and would like to keep it, but I can't see how it can be justifiable unless one makes heavy use of it (which I don't intend to).

Comment: $A\geq B$ usually means that $A-B$ is positive *semi*-definite. Moreover, positive (semi-)definiteness and using the partial ordering it induces is well established in matrix theory and its applications. So I'm not sure what's the point in avoiding the use of this concept.

Comment: @PavelJiranek Oops, I'll edit it. The point of avoiding it is that most people will be unfamiliar with the idea of partial orderings. I'm already asking my audience to grapple with a number of unfamiliar topics. I don't want to make it worse if I can help it.

Comment: I see, it of course depends on the audience. Although positive/negative (semi)-definiteness is a natural extension of (non-)(positive/negative) numbers and I believe that a subset of that audience could meet these notions later, the terminology is rather confusing sometimes. I wonder, why, e.g., a positive semi-definite matrix is not rather called non-negative definite instead to make a reasonable parallel with real numbers (however, I think I saw this somewhere already).

Comment: ...not mentioning the endless quarrels whether or not such matrices should be a priori symmetric or not :D

Comment: @PavelJiranek Indeed. The thing I'm trying to articulate in the thing I'm writing is just a sense of "bigger", that's about all that matters for my purposes. This kind of technicality (and quarrel) poses a real danger of distracting the reader from what should be a really simple and intuitive point, as well as confusing and alienating them.

Comment: @PavelJiranek This little exchange has helped me figure out what I need to write. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What about: $x^TAx\gt x^TBx$? This implies positive definiteness without the need to define it

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)